# Way to sort a string array that contains both numbers and letters numerically? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The program must have the input of a bunch of reminders with a day first, example: (Number) (Reminder).
When 0 is inputted all the reminders must be outputted in order of day. I am only unsure as to how to sort these reminders by day number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string sentence[50];
  int i = 0;
  while (sentence[i - 1] != "0") {
    cout << "Enter a day and reminder: ";
    getline(cin, sentence[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  i = 0;
  while (i <= 50 && sentence[i] != "0" && sentence[i] != "") {
    cout << sentence[i] << "\n";
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: `sentence[i - 1]` is out of bounds when `i` is 0 initially.

Comment: Your first loop invokes Undefined Behavior, as you'll try to access element -1, other then then that look at `std::sort`

Comment: you need to either parse the string or get and store the two information separately from the input stage.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), specifically, the overload which takes a comparator.

You will have to write a comparator which compares your strings using the numerical data at the beginning.

Here is an example, based on the example in cppreference link above:

```
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator()(string a, string b) const
    {
        ...
        return ...;
    }
};

std::sort(&sentence[0], &sentence[i], Comparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the numbers as numbers, and the rest of the line as text, into some structure. Define a `<` for that structure that orders things in your desired order. Sort your collection of values.

```
struct Reminder {
    int day;
    std::string text;
}

bool operator <(const Reminder & lhs, const Reminder & rhs) {
    return lhs.day < rhs.day;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& is, const Reminder & rem) {
    return is << rem.day << " " << rem.text << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Remainder> rems;
    
    for (Remainder rem; (std::cin >> rem.day) && (rem.day != 0);) {
        std::getline(std::cin, rem.text);
        rems.push_back(rem);
    }

    std::sort(rems.begin(), rems.end());

    for (const auto & rem : rems) {
        std::cout << rem;
    }
}
```